# Is there a method to send different Cell evaluation to different core?

Tags: evaluation, parallelization, cells

I am running *Mathematica* on a computer with multi CPU and every CPU has multicore. 
I am wondering if there exist a method to send different cell evaluation to different core?
So if I already have a cell being evaluating for a long time, I can still add other cells into evaluation at the same time, while won't have to stop the current evaluation or wait until the current evaluation to be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Evaluator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluator.html) option of `Cell` for this. You should define several kernels through the [`Kernel Configuration Options...`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/KernelConfigurationOptions.html) dialog, then you can use a name of configured kernel as value for the `Evaluator` option.

For example, create new local kernel with name `"My"`. Then generate an Input Cell by the following code:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 20}]]], "Input", Evaluator -> "My"]
```

In another `Cell` just type `Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 20}]` and evaluate both `Cells` with `Do` expressions simultaneously by selecting both of them and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will see that results of the evaluations are printed in parallel.

Note that the process of assigning of individual kernels to individual `Cell`s can be automatized, you aren't have to do this by hand. One way is to [make a Palette](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114542/280) with `Button`s which will attach individual kernels to the selected `Cell`s in a Notebook.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But I'm afraid that Evaluator doesn't related to my problem. I know the `Kernel Configuration`. But this option configure remote kernels. What I am talking about is multicore in one kernel.

Comment: @matheorem Multithreading is implemented in *Mathematica* through launching several kernels. It is not possible to force one kernel to perform several computations in parallel. And the `Kernel Configuration Options...` dialog allows to set up several local kernels, not only remote kernels.

Comment: What does several local kernel mean? I only have one local kernel

Comment: Local kernels are available on your local machine to perform computations. You can assign different kernels to different Noteboks and/or different Cells in one Notebook. You can also configure when these kernels should be launched: when *Mathematica* starts or only when you need them. See options in the `Kernel Configuration Options...` dialog (press the `Add` button).

Comment: I tried. But add a local kernel with a different name, doesn't work at all. Use`ExpressionCell[expr, "Input", Evaluator -> "Local"]`, two cell with different local evaluator still run in sequence.

Comment: You should assign different kernels to different Cells. For example, create new local kernel with name "My". Then generate an Input Cell by the following code: `CellPrint@
 Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 20}]]], "Input", 
  Evaluator -> "My"]`. In another Cell just type `Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 20}]` and evaluate both Cells. You will see that results of evaluation are printed in parallel.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried `CellPrint@ Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 20}]]], "Input", Evaluator -> "My"]`, it don't print the number, it print the Do expression

Comment: I wrote "**generate** an Input Cell by the following code." I meant that the generated Cell with the `Do` expression should be evaluated of course.

Comment: OK! I see. Thank you very much,Alexey Popkov! Forgive my ignorance about `CellPrint`. And I found if the function is user defined, I have to include all the related definition into the cell print. if the definition is long that will be a little inconvience. But anyway, it works in principle. You solved my problem.