# Run several input cells in parallel

Tags: parallelization, cells

I have a notebook with several input cells that produce data which is then plotted into separate graphs.

Since I do not want to save the results, because it makes the file huge, I keep the unevaluated file and run 'evaluate notebook' to produce all the plots. The cells are not sharing anything and are independent, so they could theoretically be run on separate kernels. I can run them in separate notebooks on separate kernels of course, but how can I achieve it with one notebook?

I tried to find my answer, however most applications want to run a ParallelEvaluate. However, I would like to run each cell on a separate kernel, which means that the cells run in parallel, but each cell is only run by one single kernel (so one single cell is not multithreaded).

Metaphorically speaking, I do not want a parallel running for loop within one cell, but I want four different separate for loops running in separate cells and in parallel to each other. Tell me if I use any incorrect terms or if my explanation is lacking anything.

Comment: I think you may be able to schedule your various evaluations using [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) and then start all the evaluations using [`WaitAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAll.html). See if you can adapt the examples in the `ParallelSubmit` docs.

Comment: Does that mean I have to rewrite my code into one cell with a huge ParallelSubmit? Or can I somehow refer to the other cells and submit their content directly? 

Another idea I had was through the assignment of cells to a specific kernel, but what I would actually want to do is to ask for an idle kernel and then assign the cell to that one. However, I could not find a method that gives me the idleness of a kernel.

Comment: You can try the [`Evaluator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluator.html) option of `Cell` which allows to attach individual kernels to individual cells in one notebook and run them in parallel.

Comment: Related: "[Is there a method to send different Cell evaluation to different core?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31075/280)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: I saw this as well, but I find it very annoying that I have to define which cell goes to what kernel. I would want to just schedule X cells to Y kernels. Basically just having Y parallel workers process X tasks.

Comment: @Ben Well, it is possible to make a Palette that will automatically assign individual kernels to selected `Cell`s. What is better: `ParallelSubmit` or such approach, depends on the actual goals. I just wished to give an alternative.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Thanks for the alternative! It was what I was trying to do initially, but I could not find the way to make the palette.

Comment: @Ben Please see [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114542/280) for some examples of Palettes with such functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to write all your code within [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html). You can wrap your code in `Module` or `Block` and assign it to a variable using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) so it won't be evaluated immediately.

Here is a toy example:

```
eval1 := PrimeQ[528973465287364528736543]
eval2 := Module[{}, Pause[2]; 3]

evaluators = ParallelSubmit[{eval1, eval2}]
```

[image: ready, not evaluated]

You then run the submitted code using [`WaitAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitAll.html). This returns a list containing the return values of each evaluator, in the order in which they were submitted, and also changes the state of the evaluator graphics representation to "finished"

```
WaitAll[evaluators]
(* Out: {False, 3} *)
```

[image: done]