# Cell evaluation and parallel kernels

Tags: parallelization, cells

Is it possible to simply force *Mathematica* to evaluate one cell with let's say kernel A and another cell with kernel B etc. so that they can be evaluated in parallel?
There is a similar answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31072/is-there-a-method-to-send-different-cell-evaluation-to-different-core) but I prefer avoiding creating cells manually. I would like it either in GUI or in some other simple way. The code is a plot creation. I would prefer each in separate cell. Is this even possible? Why cannot I simply right click a cell and assign a kernel :-(.

Comment: Have you seen [Run several input cells in parallel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113947/run-several-input-cells-in-parallel/113954#113954)? Would the use of `ParallelSubmit`  work for you somewhat?

Answer (score 8):

### Basic approach

At first we configure parallel kernels either via the [`Evaluation ► Kernel Configuration Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/KernelConfigurationOptions.html) menu item or programmatically via the [`EvaluatorNames`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluatorNames.html) global FrontEnd option. The following code defines 9 additional kernels which you'll able to assign to `Cell`s in a Notebook (warning: if you already changed the [Kernel Configuration Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/KernelConfigurationOptions.html), the following code will override these changes):

```
krnConfig = 
 Prepend[
  Table["krn" <> ToString[i] -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True,
                                 "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, {i, 9}], 
        "Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}]

SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames -> krnConfig]
```

> ```
> {"Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}, 
>  "krn1" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn2" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn3" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn4" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn5" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn6" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn7" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn8" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
>  "krn9" -> {"AppendNameToCellLabel" -> True, "AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}}
> ```

Then we make a Palette with buttons corresponding to assigning of each of the configured kernels to notebook selection:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column@Prepend[
   Table[With[{name = "krn" <> ToString[i]}, 
     Button[name, (SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
         Evaluator -> name];)]], {i, 9}], 
   Button[Clear, (SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
       Evaluator -> Inherited];)]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Now you can simply select a `Cell` (or even several `Cell`s or a cell group) and then press a button in order to assign the corresponding kernel to that `Cell`. If you wish to revert to the default kernel, press the `Clear` button.

Finally you can install this palette permanently by using the [`Palettes ► Install Palette...`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InstallPalette.html) menu item.

---

### Further elaboration

The above solution can be elaborated further. For example, if we wish to restrict our Palette to affect only `"Input"` `Cell`s, we can modify it as follows (*Mathematica* version 9 or higher is required):

```
CreatePalette[
 Column@Prepend[
   Table[With[{name = "krn" <> ToString[i]}, 
     Button[name, (SetOptions[#, Evaluator -> name] & /@ 
         Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], CellStyle -> "Input"];)]], {i, 9}], 
   Button[Clear, (SetOptions[#, Evaluator -> Inherited] & /@ 
       Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], CellStyle -> "Input"];)]]]
```

If we wish to assign *different* individual kernels to selected `"Input"` `Cell`s automatically, the following Palette will do this (the maximum number of individual kernels is assumed to be 9):

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[{Button["Assign individual kernels to selected Input Cells", 
    Function[cells, 
      If[TrueQ[1 <= Length[cells] <= 9], 
       MapIndexed[SetOptions[#, Evaluator -> "krn" <> ToString[#2[[1]]]] &, cells], 
       DialogInput[
        DialogNotebook[{TextCell["From 1 to 9 Input Cells must be selected"], 
          Button["OK", DialogReturn[]]}]]]][
     Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], CellStyle -> "Input"]]], 
   Button["Revert selected Input Cells to default kernel", 
    SetOptions[#, Evaluator -> Inherited] & /@ 
     Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], CellStyle -> "Input"]]}]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My license says: Controlling 2, Computing 8; the definition: controlling process indicates the number of simultaneous network users or "seats" allowed and Computation Process indicates the number of computations that may be run simultaneously. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623636/how-many-kernels-running-parallel-in-mathematica) #kers=2 but I still should have then have capacity to run 8 calculations in parallel. If I use your definition, assign krn1 to cell 1 and krn2 to cell 2 and run, I get error that it cannot launch a new kernel. Do you know why?

Comment: With my Palette I can launch 7 kernels or more simultaneously, so you probably have faced a limitation of your license. You should ask the tech support why you can't run more than 1 kernel when your license allows 8 kernels. When you receive the answer, please share it with the community.

Comment: The default kernel configuration arguments to `MLOpen` launch controlling processes instead of computing processes because of the absence of the `-subkernel` option. Appending this option doesn't work. I suspect computing processes cannot be used as cell evaluators. Computing processes are for [parallel computing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) - I'm uncertain if other uses are licensed.

Comment: @obsolesced I didn't work with `MLOpen` and can't say about licensing. I suggest you to contact the tech support.