# Variable not available in kernel despite `DistributeDefinitions`

Tags: parallelization, variable-definitions, cells

I am following [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31075/7508) answer to evaluate certain cells in a separate kernel. I have created a separate kernel called `K2` and have the following MWE:

```
myvar = 1;
DistributeDefinitions[myvar]
```

> {myvar}

Which - I believe - makes the definition of `myvar` available in all kernels.

Now I am running e.g.

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Defer[1 + 1]]], "Input", Evaluator -> "K2"]
```

which produces a cell

> 1+1

that can be evaluated (in kernel `K2`) and yields `2` (unsurprisingly). So far, so good.

Now, if I run

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData[MakeBoxes[Defer[myvar]]], "Input", Evaluator -> "K2"]
```

a cell

> myvar

is created. But evaluating it still yields only `myvar` rather than `1`. (The same holds if I omit the `Defer`).

I believe I am misunderstanding the concept of separate kernel evaluation? Ultimately, I want to send not only a variable, but a custom function to `K2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing parallel kernels (subkernels) with the ability to have multiple evaluators set up in the front end.

---

[`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) is part of the parallel tools.  Mathematica can run code in parallel by launching several "slave kernels" or subkernels and sending jobs to each.  The subkernels are controlled from by the main kernel.

---

We can also create several kernel setups through the Evaluation -> Kernel Configuration Options menu item.  Then we can assign a different evaluator to each notebook or each cell within a single notebook.  This is what the [`Evaluator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluator.html) option does.

This is a Front End feature and has absolutely no relationship to the parallel tools.  The Front End communicates directly with each evaluator you set up.  They are all "main kernels", to use the parallel tools terminology.

There is no ready made mechanism to communicate between these.  You can try to set up some sort of manual communication using [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPWolframLanguageFunctions.html).  Whether this is a reasonable idea at all depends on what you are trying to achieve.  In most cases I can imagine it isn't a good idea to do this.

Comment: Thank you! So just to understand, can I also address "slave kernels" (your option 1) from the Front End? I.e. send some cell evaluation to a subkernel such that multiple evaluations at the same time are possible (chosen from the Front End)? Or do I need to use the `Evaluator` option (your option 2) for this?

Comment: No, it is not possible to send evaluations *directly* to parallel kernels.  It can only be done using special commands evaluated in the main kernel, such as `ParallelEvaluate` and `ParallelSubmit`.  `ParallelEvaluate` will block, `ParallelSubmit` doesn't.

Comment: But (sorry for the follow up questions...) with `ParallelSubmit` I need to know _in advance_ which evaluations I want to run in parallel, correct? I.e. I cant set up some lengthy evaluation and then, while it runs, start further ones (that are evaluated simultaneously)?

Comment: No, `ParallelSubmit` doesn't block.  It returns immediately, and you can do something else while it is working.  But it is designed for parallelization, which isn't exactly what you are doing.  When I do what you describe, I also set up different kernels for different notebooks.  But then I can't share data between them, at least not automatically.